# Find the GeoArea of overlapping GeoDisks

Tags: computational-geometry, geodesy, geographics

Given a set of `GeoDisk`s, how can one determine the combined region area, presumably through `GeoArea`? `GeoDisk`s may overlap or be disjoint. Disjoint disks should sum to the total area, while overlapping disks should only contribute their union area.

With regular `Disk` objects, one can use `RegionUnion` on the set of `Disk`s and then use `Area`, and this works fine. However, there doesn't seem to be a similar "`GeoUnion`" for geographical objects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your accuracy goals, one possible way is to generate [`GeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics.html), extract out the [`Polygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html)(s), use [`BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics.html) to convert to a [`MeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion.html), extract the coordinates from the mesh, reverse order so it's `{lat, lon}`, make it back into a single Polygon, and finally use [`GeoArea`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoArea.html).

```
geoAreaDisks[d__GeoDisk] :=
 Module[{polys},
  polys = 
   Cases[InputForm[
     GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[Opacity[1]], d}, 
      GeoBackground -> None]], p_Polygon :> p, \[Infinity]];
  UnitConvert[
   GeoArea[Polygon@
     GeoPosition[
      MeshCoordinates[
        BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[polys]] /. {a_, b_} :> {b, a}]], 
   "Acres"]]

d1 = GeoDisk[Entity["City", {"Topeka", "Kansas", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Quantity[100, "Miles"]];
d2 = GeoDisk[Entity["City", {"Manhattan", "Kansas", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Quantity[75, "Miles"]];

geoAreaDisks[d1, d2]
(* Quantity[2.68948*10^7, "Acres"] *)
```

Comment: Nice work with the clever approach. It's too bad Mathematica can't do this directly with geographic regions like it does with geometric ones. Thank you.