# How to compute a list of cities within a given radius of another city?

Tags: geography

I have hitherto found a solution to this problem.

Designate a city in the continental USA as `cityCenter`.

Make a table with all large cities in the USA.   I could also just try for large cities.

Of those cities in the list, the list includes data from the continental USA.

Use a module to list all cities which match the following criteria;
distance between `cityCenter` and that city is at most a fixed radius.  If the distance is less than a fixed real number, add to final list.

Example: From San Francisco, some cities as far as Sacramento appear but not for Florida.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

This sort of thing is really easy to do in Mathematica:

```
allCities = CountryData["UnitedStates", "LargestCities"];
cityCenter = Entity["City", {"SanFrancisco", "California", "UnitedStates"}];
Select[allCities, GeoDistance[#, cityCenter] < Quantity[500, "Kilometers"] &]
```

> {San Jose, San Francisco, Fresno, Sacramento, Oakland, Bakersfield, Stockton, Reno, Fremont}

The first time you run this, it might take some time while it downloads all required data.

To input a city into a notebook, press Ctrl+= to bring up a free-form input field. You can type the name of the city in there and Mathematica will try to find the city you meant. That's how I produced `Entity["City", {"SanFrancisco", "California", "UnitedStates"}]` in this example.

Comment: This is using GeoDistance and I'm looking for TravelDistance.  Does that matter?

Comment: Thank you.  Some terms like allCitiesGeoGraphics don't seem to have definitions.

Comment: @VeritasLux Yes, you can use `TravelDistance` as well. You just need to use `TravelDistance[{#, cityCenter}]` instead of `GeoDistance[#, cityCenter]` (note the curly brackets). It will also be a lot slower than `GeoDistance`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `allCities` and `cityCenter` from Sjoerd's answer, we can also use [`GeoWithinQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoWithinQ.html) and [`GeoDisk`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoDisk.html) as follows:

```
geodisk = GeoDisk[cityCenter, Quantity[500, "Kilometers"]];

selected = Select[GeoWithinQ[geodisk]] @ allCities
```

[image]

```
GeoGraphics[{geodisk, Red, Point@ GeoPosition @ selected, 
  PointSize[Large], Blue, Point @ GeoPosition @ cityCenter}]
```

[image]

See also this closely related Q/A: [Using Geo commands, how do I get a list of cities that all meet the following criteria](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/223688/125)